# Conflicting Library Dependancy with Debian Package

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, debian-packaging

I am creating a debian package that includes a binary and a .so library. The binary is to be placed in /usr/bin and the library in /usr/lib.

The library is a very specific build of a common library that a user might already have installed. I therefore do not want to override the common version of the library with my highly specific one. How can I achieve this? Should the library be placed in another directory? I am trying to stick to the [debian package policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html)